# Swift - Image View animation

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I would like to add an animation when changing an image in imageView.

I would like to see an animation like this https://medium.com/@uthoft.jin/how-to-animate-uicollectionview-using-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-a7513add25b2 (parallex animation)

Can I get this effect in imageView or do I have to use collectionView?

Currently I use UIView.transition, but there is no option to move left / right

```
  UIView.transition(with: self.previewImageView,
                    duration:0.5,
                    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                    animations: {self.showWallpaper(index: self.indexWallpaper) },
                    completion: nil)
```

Comment: use collectionViews for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding what the goal is, but the task seems to be to slide an image view leftward while sliding another image view leftward to replace it. I can think of a dozen ways to do this, but the simplest is just to animate the sliding of the two image views. If the goal is to make it look as if the sliding is confined to specific area, wrap the action in a superview that clips to its bounds, so as to mask the image views when they are not directly in front of it.

In this example I'm driving the animation with a button, but you can drive it interactively with a gesture instead if you like; UIViewPropertyAnimator makes that sort of thing very easy.

[image]